# How can I conditionally stop a SQLite script if certain conditions are met?

Tags: sqlite

I want to be able to have a SQLite script skip executing most of the script if a condition is met at the beginning of a script.  For example, if I check for a record with a certain value in a table, and it returns zero records, I don't want to execute anything else in the script.

I have a SQLite script (SQL commands and "dot" commands in a text file) that I run by executing:

```
sqlite3 < myscript.sql
```

In my database, I have a table where IDs get stored along with a 0/1 completion status.  Near the start of the script, I have:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS _IDs AS
SELECT id FROM tbl_toComplete WHERE completed = 0;
```

After that, the rest of the script is going through and removing or updating records where the selected IDs exist:

```
BEGIN;
DELETE FROM tbl_one WHERE id IN (SELECT * FROM _IDs);
UPDATE tbl_two SET id_status = 'Removed' WHERE id IN (SELECT * FROM _IDs);
...
COMMIT;
```

Ideally, if the "SELECT id FROM tbl_toComplete WHERE completed = 0" returns no records, I don't want to process the deletions or updates.

I understand that having an empty _IDs table will result in no tables getting updated, but I'd prefer to not have the transaction take place to begin with if I don't have to.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find any solution to that problem? I'm currently at the same point.

Comment: @SebastianSchumann No, I never found a pure SQLite solution.  The best workaround I was able to find was to break the query script into a couple of different pieces and then automate them with Python.  But if anyone ever finds a way, I'd still be happy to hear it!